# How to convert Arraylist varchar to int for an sql statement?

Tags: java, android, mysql

I always get error that the arraylist in the sql statement is a varchar and not an int. And I tried to parse the arraylist in an integer variable but it keeps giving me the same error.

Code:

```
try {
                String s = getIDUsuario().toString();
                String s1 = s.split(" ")[1];
                int id = Integer.parseInt(s1.charAt(2) + "");

                Statement st = dataBase.conexionBD().createStatement();

                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(" select *  from Serveis where id_servei = " + id + "");


                while (rs.next()) {

                    bytes = rs.getBytes("imatge_servei");
                    image = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length));
                    try {
                        listaObjeto.add(new InfoServicio(getNombre(), rs.getString("titol"), rs.getString("descripcio"), getImagenPerfil(), image));


                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
```

Comment: That’s because you say it is a string (varchar) in your query when you are surrounding it with apostrophes, 'id'. Remove them and try again. But you should really be using a [prepared statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) with parameters

Comment: I do It but it's still the same

Comment: Why are you asking about `ArrayList`? There is no `ArrayList` in your code, and I don’t get the relevance?

Comment: How do you determine that the database detects it as a `varchar` even when you leave out the single quotes? Also what brand of database engine are you using, what is the data type of `id_servei` in the database, and does the query return the desired row or something else, and if so, what instead?

Comment: use sql server, id_servei type int.

Comment: If `getIDUsuario()`  returns an `ArrayList`, then `toString()` should return something like `[2, 5]`. Then `Integer.parseInt()` should throw an exception. And you should never reach the `st.executeQuery()` call. [Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please.

Comment: The parse int does not throw exceptions

Comment: To query for a number of IDs you need to use like `id_servei in (2, 5, 11)`in SQL, Using `=` will not work.

Comment: here passed all the code with something else i also did:

Comment: You will have us believe that you have successfully parsed the return value from `ArrayList.toString()` as an integer? That would be magic. No, I refuse to believe you on that point. At least until you have provided that minimal reproducible example that I have already asked for.

Comment: I said minimal. I am not reading your entire program, and I doubt that someone else will. See the link for what I mean: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Longer explanation here: http://sscce.org/.

Comment: I don't comprehend this, won't the query *always* be a String, the id is being concatenated, so it doesn't matter whether it's a varchar or an int. The parsing is of no use.

Comment: The issue is that I get this conversion error when converting varchar '[3,4]' to the int data type.

Comment: A simple query would be ```SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = N``` no ```'```. toString() of an ArrayList object would no just print the contents inside.

Comment: You can only parse Strings that *are* ints. Otherwise there's an exception. Get the characters where the values are 3 and 4, then add an empty string to them to convert them from char to String, and then parse them as ints.

Comment: Okay i try this, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you mean by `varchar '[3,4]'`,
But if you get this as a String, this is a gist of what you might want to do.

- This String does not resemble an int entirely, so you won't be able to parse it as such.

```
String e = "varchar '[3,4]'";
String e2 = e.split(" ")[1]; // Split the string at SPACE and kept the last part.
// We can see that the numbers are at index 2 & 4 of the String e2.
// Therefore
int n1 = Integer.parseInt(e2.charAt(2) + ""); // Concatenated empty String with the char because the method takes a String.
int n2 = Integer.parseInt(e2.charAt(4) + ""); // Concatenated empty String with the char because the method takes a String.
```

Comment: Can you expand on what you're actually trying to parse? is it ```varchar ['3,4']``` or just ```[3,4]```. Is it a string or something else?

Comment: I want use my arraylist  getIDUsuario() in where is statement sql

Comment: getIDUsuario() return integer arraylist

Comment: yes, but why do you want to query db for arraylist? why dont u query it for a number? if you want to query for each number inside arraylist, then you have to use a loop and query statement for each element inside arraylist. why dont u extract all elements from ur arraylist one by one, then query them?

Comment: nothing already fixed, I just complicated my life before